# How to reproduce the behaviour of Ridge(normalize=True)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics

This block of code:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

X = 'some_data'
y = 'some_target'

penalty = 1.5e-5
A = Ridge(normalize=True, alpha=penalty).fit(X, y)
```

triggers the following warning:

```
FutureWarning: 'normalize' was deprecated in version 1.0 and will be removed in 1.2.
If you wish to scale the data, use Pipeline with a StandardScaler in a preprocessing stage. To reproduce the previous behavior:

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

 - model = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(with_mean=False), Ridge())

If you wish to pass a sample_weight parameter, you need to pass it as a fit parameter to each step of the pipeline as follows:
kwargs = {s[0] + '__sample_weight': sample_weight for s in model.steps}
model.fit(X, y, **kwargs)

Set parameter alpha to: original_alpha * n_samples. 
  warnings.warn(
Ridge(alpha=1.5e-05)
```

But that codes gives me completely different coefficients, as expected because normalisation and standardisation are different.

```
B = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(with_mean=False), Ridge(alpha=penalty))
B[1].fit(B[0].fit_transform(X), y)
```

Output:

```
A.coefs[0], B[1].coefs[0]
(124.87330648168594, 125511.75051106009)
```

The result still does not match if I set `alpha = penalty * n_features`.

Output:

```
A.coefs[0], B[1].coefs[0]
(124.87330648168594, 114686.09835548172)
```

even though `Ridge()` uses a bit different normalization than I expected:

> the regressor X will be normalized by subtracting mean and dividing by
> l2-norm

So what's the proper way to use ridge regression with normalization?
considering that l2-norm seems like being obtained after prediction, data modifying and fitting again
nothing comes to my mind in context of using ridge regression from sklearn, especially after 1.2 version

---

prepare [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bu64NqQkG0YR8G2CQPkxR1EQUAJ8kCZ6/view) for experimenting:

```
url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bu64NqQkG0YR8G2CQPkxR1EQUAJ8kCZ6/view?usp=sharing'
url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=' + url.split('/')[-2]
data = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)

X = data.iloc[:,:15]
y = data['target']
```

Comment: There are many methods in `sklearn`, so it really depends on what you are trying to achieve and what data you have...

Comment: @D.L this is a showcase of ridge regression, there's no business goal behing that code, can you please tell me where should i go to choose between different methods? it seems like sklearn documentation does not help here.

Comment: the answer to this depends on what data you have and what result you are trying to arrive at...

Comment: @D.L maybe we misunderstood each other or me being unaware of something, i want to reproduce the behavior of normalising in ridge regression because it will be removed in future versions, 
if that what we both think of - can you provide me an example of doing so, depending on some specific case?
the data i have is just polynomial dataset with features as degrees of square feet from 1 to 15 (power_1, power_2, ... power_15) and i want to plot the chosen complexity of this data, that's all, i hope this helps

Comment: Note that `B[1].fit(B[0].fit_transform(X), y)` is equivalent to `B.fit(X, y)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the coefficients reported with `normalize=True` are to be applied directly to the unscaled inputs, whereas the pipeline approach applies its coefficients to *the model's* inputs, which are the scaled features.

You can "normalize" (an unfortunate overloading of the word) the coefficients by multiplying/dividing by the features' standard deviation. Together with the change to penalty suggested in the future warning, I get the same outputs:

```py
np.allclose(A.coef_, B[1].coef_ / B[0].scale_)
# True
```

(I've tested using `sklearn.datasets.load_diabetes`.)

Comment: I tried you method and it works indeed, in this dataset the mean error is unbeliveably small (12 decimal places), but in my dataset the error increases to 4 decimal places, in particular the difference betwen first coeffitients of A and B is 0.003.
I guess this method is very unstable considering those variations in precision, unfortunately.
I hope this is not the only method out there...

Comment: @Rossin 0.003 off when the coefficient is in the hundreds doesn't seem too bad. If you can provide a minimal dataset showing the discrepancy, I or others can look into it more.

Comment: i submited the file in the end of my post, feel free to experiment with it

Comment: @Rossin I get equal coefficients for your data as well.  Did you remember to modify `penalty` appropriately?

Comment: by equal you mean there's no error between the two?
i multiplied my penalty by X.shape[0], and first coeffitients(rounded to 5 digits) are A = 124.87331 , B = 124.87042. I guess i just need to stick with your solution, if there's no other way to reproduce the behavior

Comment: @Rossin ??? I get a first coefficient of `-27.146695` for both models using your data.  https://github.com/bmreiniger/datascience.stackexchange/blob/master/SO73583687_Ridge_normalize.ipynb

Comment: i messed up while uploading the target column in data, my apologies for that, i fixed it so the data should be completely fine now

Comment: also, my mistake was dividing by 
    `X.std()`
instead of 
    `B[0].scale_`
, so the error between the coeffitients became insignificant, i'm grateful for your time and help!