# Getting different values for alpha using RidgeCV with normalize=True and using Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics

I am trying to determine which `alpha` is the best in a Ridge Regression with `scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error'`.

I have an array with some values for alpha ranging from 5e09 to 5e-03:

```
array([5.00000000e+09, 3.78231664e+09, 2.86118383e+09, 2.16438064e+09,
       1.63727458e+09, 1.23853818e+09, 9.36908711e+08, 7.08737081e+08,
       5.36133611e+08, 4.05565415e+08, 3.06795364e+08, 2.32079442e+08,
       1.75559587e+08, 1.32804389e+08, 1.00461650e+08, 7.59955541e+07,
       5.74878498e+07, 4.34874501e+07, 3.28966612e+07, 2.48851178e+07,
       1.88246790e+07, 1.42401793e+07, 1.07721735e+07, 8.14875417e+06,
       6.16423370e+06, 4.66301673e+06, 3.52740116e+06, 2.66834962e+06,
       2.01850863e+06, 1.52692775e+06, 1.15506485e+06, 8.73764200e+05,
       6.60970574e+05, 5.00000000e+05, 3.78231664e+05, 2.86118383e+05,
       2.16438064e+05, 1.63727458e+05, 1.23853818e+05, 9.36908711e+04,
       7.08737081e+04, 5.36133611e+04, 4.05565415e+04, 3.06795364e+04,
       2.32079442e+04, 1.75559587e+04, 1.32804389e+04, 1.00461650e+04,
       7.59955541e+03, 5.74878498e+03, 4.34874501e+03, 3.28966612e+03,
       2.48851178e+03, 1.88246790e+03, 1.42401793e+03, 1.07721735e+03,
       8.14875417e+02, 6.16423370e+02, 4.66301673e+02, 3.52740116e+02,
       2.66834962e+02, 2.01850863e+02, 1.52692775e+02, 1.15506485e+02,
       8.73764200e+01, 6.60970574e+01, 5.00000000e+01, 3.78231664e+01,
       2.86118383e+01, 2.16438064e+01, 1.63727458e+01, 1.23853818e+01,
       9.36908711e+00, 7.08737081e+00, 5.36133611e+00, 4.05565415e+00,
       3.06795364e+00, 2.32079442e+00, 1.75559587e+00, 1.32804389e+00,
       1.00461650e+00, 7.59955541e-01, 5.74878498e-01, 4.34874501e-01,
       3.28966612e-01, 2.48851178e-01, 1.88246790e-01, 1.42401793e-01,
       1.07721735e-01, 8.14875417e-02, 6.16423370e-02, 4.66301673e-02,
       3.52740116e-02, 2.66834962e-02, 2.01850863e-02, 1.52692775e-02,
       1.15506485e-02, 8.73764200e-03, 6.60970574e-03, 5.00000000e-03])
```

Then, I used `RidgeCV` to try and determine which of these values would be best:

```
ridgecv = RidgeCV(alphas = alphas, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', 
                  normalize = True, cv=KFold(10))
ridgecv.fit(X_train, y_train)
ridgecv.alpha_
```

and I got `ridgecv.alpha_ = 0.006609705742330144`

However, I received a warning that `normalize = True` is deprecated and will be removed in version 1.2. The warning advised me to use `Pipeline` and `StandardScaler` instead. Then, following instructions of how to do a `Pipeline`, I did:

```
steps = [
    ('scalar', StandardScaler(with_mean=False)),
    ('model',RidgeCV(alphas=alphas, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', cv=KFold(10)))
]

ridge_pipe2 = Pipeline(steps)
ridge_pipe2.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = ridge_pipe.predict(X_test)

ridge_pipe2.named_steps.model.alpha_
```

Doing this way, I got `ridge_pipe2.named_steps.model.alpha_ = 1.328043891473342`

For a last check, I also used `GridSearchCV` as follows:

```
steps = [
    ('scalar', StandardScaler()),
    ('model',Ridge())
]

ridge_pipe = Pipeline(steps)
ridge_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

parameters = [{'model__alpha':alphas}]


grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = ridge_pipe,
                          param_grid = parameters,
                          scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error',
                          cv = 10,
                          n_jobs = -1)

grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train) 
grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params
```

where I got `grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params = 1.328043891473342` (same as the other `Pipeline` approach).

Therefore, my question... why normalizing my dataset with `normalize=True` or with `StandardScaler()` yields different best `alpha` values?

Comment: A related recent question (about coefficients and `Ridge` rather than optimal alpha and `RidgeCV`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73583687/10495893

Comment: @BenReiniger thanks for that. Should you maybe roll that one out as an answer? Or you reckon I should just delete this post as it wouldn't be helpful to have it?

Comment: I'll see how that answer fares/translates here when I have a chance (unless another answerer beats me to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding warning message for ordinary `Ridge` makes an additional mention:

> Set parameter alpha to: original_alpha * n_samples.

(I don't entirely understand why this is, but for now I'm willing to leave it.  There should probably be a note added into the warning for `RidgeCV` along these lines.)  Changing your `alphas` parameter in the second approach to `[alph * X.shape[0] for alph in alphas]` should work.  The selected `alpha_` will be different, but rescaling again `ridge_pipe2.named_steps.model.alpha_ / X.shape[0]` and I retrieve the same value as in the first approach (as well as the same rescaled coefficients).

(I've used the dataset shared in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73583687/10495893), and added the experiment to [the notebook](https://github.com/bmreiniger/datascience.stackexchange/blob/master/SO73583687_Ridge_normalize.ipynb) I created there.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the same cross validation is used and scale without centering the data.

When you run with normalize=True, you get this as part of the warning :

```
If you wish to scale the data, use Pipeline with a StandardScaler in a preprocessing stage. To reproduce the previous behavior:

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

model = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(with_mean=False), Ridge())
```

Regarding the cv, if you check the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.html), RidgeCV by default performs leave-one-out cross validation :

```
Ridge regression with built-in cross-validation.
See glossary entry for cross-validation estimator.
By default, it performs efficient Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation.
```

So to get the same result, we can define a cross-validation to use :

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

kf = KFold(10)

X_train, y_train = datasets.make_regression()

alphas = [0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1]

ridgecv = RidgeCV(alphas = alphas, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', normalize = True, cv=KFold(10))
ridgecv.fit(X_train, y_train)
ridgecv.alpha_
0.001
```

And use it on pipeline :

```
steps = [
    ('scalar', StandardScaler(with_mean=False)),
    ('model',RidgeCV(alphas=alphas, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error',cv=kf))
]

ridge_pipe2 = Pipeline(steps)
ridge_pipe2.fit(X_train, y_train)

ridge_pipe2.named_steps.model.alpha_
0.001
```

Comment: I still get different values. If I add `cv=KFold(10)` and `with_mean=False`, I now get `ridgecv.alpha_ = 0.006609705742330144`, which is different than before but still not the same as `1.328043891473342` that I get with both `Pipeline` examples. But I believe it's what @Ben said, `normalize` and `StandardScaler` perform different calculations to the data, so it is expected them to yield different results.

Comment: did you feed the same KFold into Pipeline ?

Comment: Yes. I have edited my answer with the new code.